# Android: Adding a setOnTouchListener without overriding an existing one?

Tags: android

**Goal**: I have a custom button that already contains functionality onTouch that I would like to keep but add functionality on top of.

**Problem**: Adding an onTouch like so overrides the original custom button functionality, thus no longer doing the original needed behavior. Having the annotation "@Override" or not doesn't change anything:

```
myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(event);
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //Extra behavior needed
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The custom button itself:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Original needed behavior. Need to keep.
                break;
            ...
        }
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Any solutions one can look into? Thank you!

Comment: The @Override will only check if the method is available in the superclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the public method in CustomButton class

```
myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //try adding this line
                boolean touchResult = myButton.onTouch(v, event);
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //Extra behavior needed
                    return true;
                }
                return (false||touchResult);
            }
        });
```

Adding touch result variable makes sure that you handle the touch at both the places.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will lead to `StackOverFlowException`, because you are calling `myButton.onTouch()` within touch listener, which will result in calling that callback again endlessly.

Comment: I am not sure about the behavior, I guess there are two independent touch items here. Try this code, There is one more solution, I have to cross check though

Comment: I think you are just calling the same function within a function (recursion). See, you are in `onTouch()` function of `CustomButton` class. And you are calling `onTouch()` function from it. Why won't it cause endless recursion?

Comment: Yea, this code should work, the moment you add touch listener to view, previous touch listener is replaced by the new one, So you can call the previous touch listener with the new one without looping.

Comment: Let's see what @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy will come up with :-) I personally think this should not work as expected.

Comment: aziz, don't get confused, the touch listener you implemented in custom class is one instance, and the new touch listener that you are assigning is another one, both are different objects. Its calling object of same class with another of object. Class is same, objects are different

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thank you so much Mohammed! Sometimes it's the uncomplicated solutions that get us.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already having custom Button implementation (`CustomButton`) you may need to override its `setOnTouchListener` method to look like:

```
@Override
public void setOnTouchListener(final OnTouchListener l) {
    OnTouchListener wrapperListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean myButtonTouchListenerResult = CustomButton.this.onTouch(v, event);
            boolean wrappedTouchListenerResult = l.onTouch(v, event);
            return myButtonTouchListenerResult || wrappedTouchListenerResult;
        }
    }
    super.setOnTouchListener(wrapperListener);
}
```

That would ensure original `onTouchListener` remains when someone from outside assigns another instance to it.